# attachClickHandler error while login using google in Angular

Tags: angular, oauth, google-oauth

I am trying to implement social login using google in my angular project

here is my relevant login html code

```
 <button (click)="prepareLoginButton()" #googleSignUp >Login Using Google</button>
```

here is my relevant ts code

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    
    @ViewChild('googleSignUp', { static: true })
    googleSignUp: ElementRef;
    
    auth2: any;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.googleSDK();
    }
    //google login
    prepareLoginButton() {
        this.auth2.attachClickHandler(
            this.googleSignUp.nativeElement,
            {},
            (googleUser) => {
                let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                this.socialLogin.id = profile.getId();
                this.socialLogin.fullName = profile.getName();
                this.socialLogin.email = profile.getEmail();
                this.socialService.setSocialDetails(this.socialLogin);
            },
            (error) => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            }
        );
    }
    googleSDK() {
        window['googleSDKLoaded'] = () => {
            window['gapi'].load('auth2', () => {
                this.auth2 = window['gapi'].auth2.init({
                    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                    scope: 'profile email'
                });
                this.prepareLoginButton();
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js,
                fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=googleSDKLoaded';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        })(document, 'script', 'google-jssdk');
    }
}
```

I have been facing this error for a long time

please tell how to fix it

here is the error i get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you or not but for one you're calling `prepareLoginButton` in the load method and also when the user clicks the button, which is probably not what you want.

You can call `gapi.load` from angular like

```
declare const gapi: any; //put this ABOVE your @Component (after imports)

private googleSDK() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: environment.googleClientId,
        cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email',
      });
      this.prepareLoginButton();
    });
  }
```